# Testing feature/branches independently?

Tags: manual-testing

Im not sure what you would call this exactly, or what kind of testing:

But say you have your main branch for Product A, (lets assume we are using Git). Bob creates a branch to work on Feature XXY, Bob needs to test XXY.

So besides Unit Tests that are ran against the XXY Branch, what are other ways to test such a branch...and what is this kind of testing even called?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some time ago we had a tool installed on a server named `testManager` which has a simple GUI to switch branches on a server. If you can manage the project specific points of your tests (times for each branch and config files for several databases etc.) you can use this tool for testing different branches on a testserver. But as said you can only one branch at one time.

I tried to google the tool but I didn't found it and the dev who brought it in has gone and we dropt the tool as we changed our server structure some years ago.